# parseInt is returning NaN for CSS property for total values

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

So basically i am trying to insert style into the table that loads data from a php file (php file is pulling it from mysql)  and The JavaScript show the data into the table and as well as calculates the totals/averages of the data shown.

My PHP file contains my table's data.

```
   $data .= "['$offer_name','$clicks', '$leads', '$$revenue', '$crate%', '$$avgCPA', '$$epc'],";
```

And my tpl file that contains the html/css also contains the JavaScript that loads the data from PHP

```
    {literal}
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

     $('#dataGrid').dataTable( {
    "fnFooterCallback": function ( nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay ) {

        var clicks = 0;
        var downloads = 0;
        var conv = 0;
        var avgCPA = 0;
        var epc = 0;
        var revenue = 0;
        var conv_ = 0;

       for ( var i=0 ; i<aaData.length ; i++ )
        {
            clicks += parseInt(aaData[i][1]);
            downloads += parseInt(aaData[i][2]);
            conv += parseFloat(aaData[i][4]);
            avgCPA += parseFloat(aaData[i][5].substring(1));
            epc += parseFloat(aaData[i][6].substring(1));
            revenue += parseFloat(aaData[i][3].substring(1));
        }

        revenue = Math.round(revenue*100)/100;
        conv_ = (clicks == 0) ? 0 : (downloads/clicks)*100;
        //conv = conv_.toString().match(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/);
        conv = Math.round(conv_);
        avgCPA = (downloads == 0) ? 0 : Math.round((revenue/downloads)*100)/100;
        epc = (clicks == 0) ? 0 : Math.round((revenue/clicks)*100)/100;

        var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
        nCells[1].innerHTML = clicks;
        nCells[2].innerHTML = downloads;
        nCells[3].innerHTML = '$'+revenue;
        nCells[4].innerHTML = conv+'%';
        nCells[5].innerHTML =  '$'+avgCPA;
        nCells[6].innerHTML =  '$'+epc;
    },

   {/literal}
   "aaData": [{$data}],

   {literal}          

       });

    });

    </script>
    {/literal}
```

Here are the results, its working properly and calculating the correct data

```
        Total/Average   10      10      $48.9       100%     $4.89     $4.89
```

But when i try to add style ( i have tried both inline style and using css ) to the php code

```
    $data .= "[';$offer_name','<span class=\"tabclicks\">$clicks</span>', '<span class=\"tableads\">$leads</span>', '<span class=\"tabrevenue\">$$revenue</span>', '<span class=\"tabconv\">$crate%</span>', '<span class=\"tabcpa\">$$avgCPA</span>', '<span class=\"tabepc\">$$epc</span>'],";
```

The table is loading the data just fine mean the style is working but the java script is returning NaN in return for the totals/averages

```
    Total/Average       NaN     NaN     $NaN        NaN%        $NaN        $NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you add more text (html) around your numbers, they cannot be parsed as Int. You should keep the data clean and you may add class name directly to nCells elements.

```
nCells[1].className = "tabclicks";
// etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. Though your solution applies the class to the last row ( Totals/Averages ) but not the rest of the table. http://prntscr.com/7sq0pg